# Problema ao excluir item em um arquivo json

Tags: json, node.js

**Ao acessar essa rota que exclui um item:**

```
app.get("/excluir/:id/:categoria", (req, res) => {
  let dados = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./data/dados.json", "utf8"));

  var id = req.params.id;
  var categoria = req.params.categoria;

  console.log(id, categoria);

  for (var i = 0; i < dados.length; i++) {
    if (dados[i].id == id && dados[i].categoria) {
      delete dados[i];
    }
  }

  dados = dados.filter(function (el) {
    return el != null;
  });

  fs.writeFile("./data/dados.json", JSON.stringify(dados, null, 2), function (
    err
  ) {
    if (!err) return res.send("Write file error!");
  });

  console.log(dados);

  res.redirect("/cardapio");
});
```

**Meu navegador fica desse jeito:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Mas se eu recarregar a aba ele funciona perfeitamente.**

Comment: Amigo, remova a primeira imagem e coloque o código escrito. Depois selecione o código e aperte Ctrl + K

Comment: Este erro não tem a ver com seu código, e sim, que o servidor em localhost não está rodando. Acontece em uma mesma sessão somente com esta rota, as outras funcionam normalmente?

Comment: Percebi que o problema esta na parte da escrita no arquivo, ele não esta esperando escrever no arquivo para depois executar a próxima linha, por isso que quando eu atualizo da certo, poque ja deu tempo ele terminar a execução.

Answer (score 1):

Espere a gravação assíncrona dos dados e só depois encerre a requisição, se não o express não conseguirá escrever os headers corretamente.

```
fs.writeFile("./data/dados.json", JSON.stringify(dados, null, 2), function (
  err
) {
  // com o !err o express tentava enviar 2 respostas ao navegador..
  if (err) { return res.send("Write file error!"); }
  console.log(dados);
  res.redirect("/cardapio");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Voce comparou `dados[i].id == id` que se for verdadeiro vai retornar um True, e em seguida voce com um operador booleano (&&) chama o `dados[i].categoria`  e se a categoria nao for um true esse if sempre vai dar falso e o código  `delete dados[i];` nunca vai ser executado,
Agora a pagina de not found pode ser algum erro no redirecionamento.